# Consulta mysql devuelve null con salto de pagina, del tipo r = "null ↵"

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, null

Consulta mysql devuelve null con salto de pagina, del tipo r = "null ↵" y cuando quiero validar x="null" no lo identifica por ese caracter, ya intente cambiar las consultas, y demas y sigo con el mismo error, alguien tiene alguna idea de como corregir?

Comment: Habría que ver porqué esperas una cadena "null" en lugar de un valor nulo y cómo es que se coló ese caracter. Edita tu pregunta y agrega el código que usas para guardar y leer tus registros.

Comment: falta información, incluye tu query y la definición de tablas, código involucrado, etc.